# Magento 1.6.1.0 compatible with PHP 5.6?

Tags: php

I have two Magento installations running versions 1.6.1.0 and 1.7.0.0. I am looking to upgrade my server to PHP 5.6 and Google wasn't particularly convincing that this is possible.

Can someone please confirm with certainty if 1.6.1.0 and 1.7.0.0 run properly under PHP 5.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento does not officially support 5.6 at *any* version, nevermind the older 1.6.x.

At present there are patches for 1.8 and 1.9 for PHP 5.5 support.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html

Comment: Excellent. Not sure why that result didn't appear in my searches, they might have been too specific. Upvoted and marked as correct - thanks :)