# If I update from php 5.4 to 5.5 on the server, will the 1.8.1 store have problem?

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0

To install Magento 2 for new site, I need to update php from 5.4 to 5.5 on my server.

There will be any issue or problem on our 1.8.1 store after update php from 5.4 to 5.5?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91005/magento-1-6-1-0-compatible-with-php-5-6

Answer (score 1):

in system requirements there is only patch for php 5.4
but it works on php 5.5 without  any serious problems. 
[Magento 1.6.1.0 compatible with PHP 5.6?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91005/magento-1-6-1-0-compatible-with-php-5-6)

anyway if you see any issues it will be pretty easy to fix them.